# What is a level 2 WebDAV server?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, webdav

I am doing some research into WebDAV and have been specifically looking at Apache Tomcat as an implementation of it. In the docs for the WebdavServlet class that comes with Tomcat I have noticed a reference to a "level 2" WebDAV servlet. This reference is also made on the Apache Tomcat WebDAV docs page. I cannot find any documentation or explanation anywhere beyond these 2 pages about what this means, if someone could fill me in that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A WebDAV level 2 (or class 2) server is one that implements WebDAV compliance class 2; see [RFC4918 Chapter 18](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html#dav.compliance.classes).  Compliance class 2 includes all WebDAV mandatory functionality plus the optional functionality related to locking.  The compliance level / class of a server is given in the `DAV` response header.

A lot of clients will treat a level 1 WebDAV server as read-only, since WebDAV update functions are not entirely safe unless the updates are performed while the relevant resources are locked.

**UPDATE**: Christopher Schultz (one of the Tomcat developers) noted that he has committed changes to the `WebdavServlet` javadoc to include links to RFC 4918 and explain the compliance level.  These changes should be published in the next Tomcat release.

Comment: I've added references to the RFC, and specifically the compliance class section, to the `WebdavServlet` javadoc.